# How to achieve pixelated distortion glitch

Tags: adobe-illustrator, distort

I want to achieve a certain kind of distortion.

Take this image I want to reproduce in Illustrator:

[image]

I am aware that there is first some kind of mesh distort going on, what I don't understand is **how to add the texture.**

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want to use a clipping mask(s).

[image]

[image]

You are going to take your texture, align it over your letter/shape then copy that letter and use it to make your mask.

Answer (score 0):

The image seems to be some sort of pixel glitch effect, so Illustrator would not be my first choice to create something like that.

Pixels are raster, but Illustrator is a vector image editor with pretty limited raster effects/raster editing capabilities. It's really the wrong kind of software.

There's an online glitch creator [here](https://snorpey.github.io/jpg-glitch/) - I have no affiliation with this website.

Obviously, glitch effects are somewhat random, so it's not going to replicate the effect in your example exactly. And you'll have to mess around with the controls until you get something you like.

Here's an example created with the online glitch generator I linked to.

[image]

From there, you could open it in a raster image editor, such as Photoshop, GIMP or similar, desaturate it, then convert it into an Indexed Color image, set the number of colours to 3, and apply pattern dithering.

This example was created in Photoshop

[image]